# Calculate pending time to finish processing threaded code C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, runtime

I have a code with threads and I want to show the pending time to finish processing. The button1 calls the 
function "Function1()" that reads a file in chunks of 1024 bytes controlled in a while loop until get end 
of file. Within the "While loop" there is a "foreach loop" where is called the "Function2()". I'm starting 
the timer at the beginning of "while loop" and stopping it at the end of "while loop". After that I'm trying 
to calculate aprox the Pending time knowing first the number of iterations that will be processed by "while loop".
Then I save the "elapsed time for the first iteration" (lets say T1) and then I multiply it by number of iterations.

This would be

```
PendingTime = T1*Iterations.
```

Then I do

```
PendingTime = PendingTime - Ti, where Ti is the ElapsedTime of the ith iteration.
```

The issue is when I try with the real code, the multiplation of T1*Iterations gives me 402s and actually
the processing takes 12s.

Maybe some expert could see what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

The code looks like this:

```
    async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Some code
        await Task.Run(() => Function1(inputfile, cts.Token), cts.Token);
        //Some code
    }

    public void Function2()
    {
        //Some code
    }       

    public void Function1(string inputfile, CancellationToken token)
    {
        int buffer = 1024;
        int IterationCounter = 0;
        decimal Iterations = 1;  
        int PendingTime = 0;            

        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(inputfile, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            FileLength = (int)reader.BaseStream.Length;
            Iterations = (int)FileLength/buffer;                            

            while (chunk.Length > 0)
            {     
                Stopwatch sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew(); //Start time counter              
                //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                //some code 
                chunk = reader.ReadBytes(buffer);

                foreach (byte data in chunk)
                {
                    //Some code
                    Function2(); //Call to Function2
                }
                //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 

                //Checking if it is the first iteration to save the pending time
                //Pending time would be the elapsed time for the first iteration
                //multiplied by the number of iterations (FileLength/1024).
                sw1.Stop(); //Stop time counter

                if (IterationCounter == 1)
                {
                    PendingTime =  (int)((decimal)Math.Round(sw1.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / 1000, 4)*Iterations);                      
                }                   
                //Show in TexBox1 the pending time
                TextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    PendingTime = PendingTime - (int)Math.Round(sw1.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / 1000, 4);                 
                    TextBox1.Text = PendingTime + " s";
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

I'm testing with the following code based on the example of Peter Duniho.

It can be tested with any file(i.e. txt file). I've tested with a txt file of 5MB and execution time was 3 seconds, but the pending time appear always as zero in TextBox1. Where I'm wrong?

Note: I changed this:

```
double timePerIteration = sw1.Elapsed / ++IterationCounter;
```

to this

```
double timePerIteration = sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000/ ++IterationCounter;
```

Since I was getting the error:

```
Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.TimeSpan' and 'int' (CS0019)
```

The code so far is. Thanks for help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestTimer
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        string filename = "";
        long FileLength;
        FileInfo fInfo;
        Stopwatch sw1 =  new Stopwatch();

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void BtnSelectFileClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Title = "Select file";
            DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();

            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filename = ofd.FileName;
                fInfo = new FileInfo(filename);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File not found");
                return;
            }           
        }   

        async void BtnRunProcessClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();            
            await Task.Run(() => Function1(filename, cts.Token), cts.Token);    
        }

    public void Function1(string inputfile, CancellationToken token)
    {
        int buffer = 1024;
        int IterationCounter = 0;
        int Iterations = 0;  
        double pendingTime = 0;            

        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(inputfile, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            FileLength = (int)reader.BaseStream.Length;
            Iterations = (int)FileLength/buffer;                           
            byte[] chunk;          

            sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew(); //Start time counter

            while (true)
            {                               
                chunk = reader.ReadBytes(buffer);

                if (chunk.Length == 0) {break;}

                foreach  (byte data in chunk)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(90/100);
                }

                // pendingTime is the current average time-per-iteration,
                // times the number of iterations left
                double timePerIteration = sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000/ ++IterationCounter;
                pendingTime = timePerIteration * (Iterations - IterationCounter);

                TextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    // Let string.Format() take care of rounding for you
                    TextBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:0} s", pendingTime / 1000);
                });
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Execution time: " + string.Format("{0:0} s", sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000) );
        }
    }               

    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing that guarantees that each iteration will take the same time, so I would suggest you average it out by `time taken so far / number of iterations so far`, and use that to calculate the estimated time remaining.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the suggestion. I'll try to do that. The thing is that would be a fix value harcoded and if I try in a slower or faster computer the time will vary.

Comment: It wouldn't be fixed, it would be based on the time the operation has taken so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how the code you posted ever actually compiled, never mind worked. The `FileLength` variable does not appear to be declared, and you never increment the `IterationCounter` variable, giving you a negative `PendingTime` value with each iteration. Even if you had incremented the counter, your `PendingTime` variable's actual meaning changes from the block that executes when the counter is `1` and a little later when you subtract your elapsed time from the current `PendingTime` variable.

That suggests the code you posted isn't really the code you're using, since the displayed time remaining would always have been negative (even assuming the declaration of `FileLength` just got accidently dropped from your post for some reason). For the sake of argument, I'll add a statement that does the increment…

As commenter Chris says, when each iteration's actual duration can vary, as it seems to be the case here, the best you're going to do is average all of the iterations up to the current one. Even that may lead to an erroneous time-remaining display, with a fair amount of variation from iteration to iteration (especially if the number of iterations is small), but at least it's more likely to be close.

Something like this would likely work better for you:

```
public void Function1(string inputfile, CancellationToken token)
{
    int buffer = 1024;
    int IterationCounter = 0;
    int Iterations;

    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(inputfile, FileMode.Open)))
    {
        if (reader.BaseStream.Length == 0)
        {
            // nothing to do
            return;
        }

        // NOTE: this won't work for files with length > int.MaxValue!
        // Your original code has the same limitation, and I have not
        // bothered to change that.

        // Now that we know for sure the length is > 0, we can
        // do the following to ensure a correct iteration count
        Iterations = ((int)reader.BaseStream.Length - 1) / buffer + 1;

        Stopwatch sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        while (chunk.Length > 0)
        {     
            //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            //some code 
            chunk = reader.ReadBytes(buffer);

            foreach (byte data in chunk)
            {
                //Some code
                Function2(); //Call to Function2
            }
            //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 

            // pendingTime is the current average time-per-iteration,
            // times the number of iterations left
            double timePerIteration = sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds / ++IterationCounter,
                pendingTime = timePerIteration *
                    (Iterations - IterationCounter);

            //Show in TexBox1 the pending time
            TextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                // Let string.Format() take care of rounding for you
                TextBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:0} s", pendingTime / 1000);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Unless you are guaranteed that your input file is always exactly a multiple of 1024 bytes in length, you also had a bug in your calculation of the total iteration count. I fixed that in the above as well.

Comment: Hi Peter. Please may you see my update to original post. I've tested your code but it doesn't shows me the pending time correctly. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. The reason it didn't work after you fixed it so that it compiled is that you introduced an extra "/ 1000", and since your operation never was going to take more than 1000 seconds, the displayed value was always 0. I have edited my code to show the correct way to fix the compiler error (i.e. simply use `ElapsedMilliseconds` instead of `Elapsed`...no other change needed). Note that the conversion of ms to seconds is done when setting the text, so it's not needed in the actual calculation.

Comment: Hi Peter. It happens the same with the modification you suggested. I'm not sure what happens. I see your logic is correct. If you test my code I put in the Update with any file about 10 MB you'll see that the overall time is shown correctly but in TexBox1 always appears 0.

Comment: When you debug it, what values are you seeing for the `timePerIteration ` and `pendingTime` variables? What about the `Iterations` and `IterationCounter` variables? Is the whole operation still taking the 3-12 seconds you reported in your question?

Comment: Hi Peter. I'm not sure why. Maybe because Texbox it needs some time to update the value, but this time appears the pending time in textbox when I add "Thread.Sleep(1);" below the line "TextBox1.Text=...". For the file I tested begins in 20s and decreases until get to 0s, but actual overall time is 12 s. I think this is normal because it is an aproximation using the average like you said. Thank again for the help